# How to exclude minus sign using regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex, oracle-adf

I need to check whether user is entering *minus sign* or not at the start of the values.
If user is entering minus sign then it should throw error.
Tried different pattern `^(\\d*|\\s*)$`

Comment: var val = 'user input';

val.match(/-/) !== null  <<< not null means there's a minus sign in the string.

Comment: ^(\\d*|\\s*)$ 
tried this pattern

Comment: try `/[^a-zA-Z0-9*?:.+\-^"_ ]+/g`

Comment: The pattern you tried will match an empty value, a value of all digits, or a value of all whitespace. It will not match any value with minus sign in it. That is what is does, but it's unclear what it is you *want* it to do, since that doesn't seem to be what you want. You *say* you want to know if there is a minus sign *at the start* of the value. Does that mean first character, or could there be whitespace before it? You say to fail if it starts with minus sign, implying that it will be accepted *for all other values*, however your regex says otherwise. So, what it is *exactly* you want?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but agree with Andreas that the question is unclear. The title asks to "exclude" the minus sign, but the description asks to "throw an error". Without clear requirements it's difficult to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `.indexOf`

```
var val = "Whatever-is-the input";
if(val.indexOf("-")!=-1){
  // there is a - in input
}
```

Comment: ```val.indexOf("-") > 0```?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **indexOf()** which  returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.

As an example:

```
var userInput = "some-user-input";
if(userInput.indexOf("-") != -1) {
   // do some magic here
}
```